# Copy Range of Data based on Cell Value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list with columns A to C. Column B contains either "A" "B" or "C". I need to copy all data from columns A to C to a new sheet depending on the value in column B.

[image: sample data]

I want to copy to sheet 1 when column B is "A", to sheet 2 when column B is "B", and to sheet 3 when column B is "C".

I've tried VBA using `For i = 1 to .End(xlUp).Offset(0)`, but then what should I do? What I tried wasn't working at all for me.

Answer (score 0):

The code below assumes the sheet containing the data to be copied is named "Main". It also assumes your "paste" sheets contain column headers, so it will start pasting at row 2.  If that's not what you want, remove the `.Offset(1, 0)` call from the line doing the pasting.

You'll probably want better error handling than the one `Debug.Print` line, but I'll leave that up to you.

Tested in Excel 2007, and functioning as expected.

```
Sub DoCopy()

  Const copySheetName As String = "Main"
  Dim rw As Integer
  Dim lngRowStart As Long
  Dim lngRowEnd As Long

  Dim copySheet As Excel.Worksheet: Set copySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(copySheetName)
  Dim pasteSheet As Excel.Worksheet

  lngRowStart = 1 'number of first row containing data to copy
  lngRowEnd = 17  'number of last row containing data to copy

  'the "Copy" sheet be the active sheet in order to copy/paste (avoid run-time error 1004)
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(copySheetName).Activate

  For rw = lngRowStart To lngRowEnd

    copySheet.Range(Cells(rw, 1), Cells(rw, 3)).Copy

    Select Case Cells(rw, 2)
      Case "a"
        Set pasteSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
      Case "b"
        Set pasteSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
      Case "c"
        Set pasteSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
      Case Else
        Debug.Print "Invalid Value: " & Cells(rw, 2) & " (row " & rw & ")"
        GoTo SkipRow
    End Select

    pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

SkipRow:
  Next rw

  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Set copySheet = Nothing
  Set pasteSheet = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx I will try, really appreciate your help

Comment: One more question， can "a" as the critieria changes to cell value

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Would you please rephrase?

Comment: Sorry, I saw was formulae using CASE function, and wondering if it's possible to change the Case "a", Case "b" to a cell value, say cell "A1" and so I can type the criteria on cell A1 to get a result

Comment: You can refer to the value of a specific cell using the ’Cells’ function. But you would want different arguments to it for each ’Case’.

Comment: @KeithSo, the reason I haven't replied until now is that you erroneously posted an Answer instead of a Comment, so I did not receive any notification. The only reason I'm responding now is that I clicked on this post by mistake, and noticed your Answer. Anyway, assuming you still need help: As I said, the code I posted was tested and functions as expected. So, what do you mean by "hanged"? Did you receive an error on that line? If so, please post it. And, are you sure your sheet is named "data"? If that's the only change you made to the code, there's no reason why it shouldn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but i just got time to test this and doesn't work.  It hanged during the "
  Dim copySheet As Excel.Worksheet: Set copySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(copySheetName)"

my original data in the sheet "data", I already updated the name to be   Const copySheetName As String = "data"

do you have any idea why it doesnt work.
Thank you.